# Convert from String to Date throws Unparseable date exception

Tags: java, datetime, time, datetime-format

I want to convert a Date to a String but I have some problems. My code is this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");

    String hacer = "Fri Nov 01 10:30:02 PDT 2013";
    Date test = null;
    test = formato.parse( hacer);
    System.out.println("prueba===>" + test);
```

But nothing something is wrong eclipse shows me this error:

```
Unparseable date: "Fri Nov 01 10:30:02 PDT 2013"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
```

some help?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Maybe you didn't recompile the code after making a change.

Comment: Worked for me, too.  prueba===>Fri Nov 01 13:30:02 EDT 2013

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably your default locale doesn't support English months in MMM. For example in Poland MMM supports "styczeń" but not "Jan" or "January"

To change this In `SimpleDateFormat` you need to set locale which supports months written in English, for example

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: thanks, adding Locale.ENGLISH works, what is the difference? 
why not works before putting that?

Comment: @Chris: It affects how to parse the date. You can check which one is your default with `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());`.

Comment: Probably your default locale doesn't support English months in `MMM`. For example I live in Poland and MMM supports `"styczeń"` but not `"Jan"` or `"January"`.

Comment: actually  I try with: System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
and my default locale not supports English, but now works whit Locale.ENGLISH

Comment: @Chris Then your problem is solved. Also if you don't want to pass each time `Locale.ENGLISH` in `SimpleDateFormat` constructor you can set your global locale to ENGLISH with `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);` before you use `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");`

Comment: Setting the global locale is usually not recommended; it's fighting against the _user's_ system configuration. If you really need to do the parsing in a specific locale, write it explicitly.

Comment: @DonalFellows Yes that is true thanks for pointing that. I agree and that is why I just mentioned it in comment as additional info and didn't include it in answer to not encourage others to use this way. With your comment it is more obvious. +1.